# How can I pull xray raw data to Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-xray

I am running serverless application on AWS includes `lambda`, `ECS Fargate`, `dynamodb`. I have enabled xray in some of the services and I'd like to push all xray raw data to `Elasticsearch` for analysis. I know xray has API to retrieve raw data but I am now sure how I can use it to continuously push xray data to ES. What I am thinking is to trigger a lambda whenever there is a xray raw data available. And the lambda push the data to Elasticsarch cluster.

But I don't know how to do that and there isn't any doc to describe it. Or whether I can link xray directly to ES cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, the X-Ray daemon sends partial trace data to the service backend. The service aggregates this data in the form of an end-to-end trace and displays in the console. The X-Ray service does not generate an event which can trigger your lambda function. Maybe you can have the lambda function run periodically and retrieve trace data using the API, and then send it to Elasticsearch.
X-Ray does not provide the functionality to export the trace data currently.